# The position of a particle at any time $t$ is given by $S = V0/a [1-e^{-at}]$. What are the dimensions of $a$ and $V_0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, dimensional-analysis

To find the dimensions of  and V0, I must know the dimension of S and e. So I want to know it.

Comment: If it's your homework you should show that you've tried to solve this, I guess.

Comment: I tried and that's why i am seeking help from others to find the dimensions of S and e.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if someone is asking about the dimensions of $e$ (Wow!!!), this isn't really about physics at all.

Answer (score 4):

The position of the particle at a time $t$ is given by,

$$S(t)=\frac{V_0}{a}(1-e^{-at})$$

As it denotes position, $[S]=\text{m}$, i.e. distance in meters. If you look at the exponential, $\exp(at)$, notice that the argument $at$ **must be dimensionless**, hence $[a]=\text{s}^{-1}$ or inverse time. Now,

$$\frac{[V_0]}{[a]}=[V_0]\text{s}=\text{m}$$

hence $V_0$ has dimensions of velocity, i.e. $[V_0]=\text{ms}^{-1}$. (Note: $e$ is dimensionless, it is Euler's constant, the base of natural logarithms and approximately $2.71828$).

---

Why must the argument of an exponential be dimensionless? We can expand it as a series,

$$\exp(x)=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \dots$$

Hence if $x$ had dimensions, say of distance, we'd be adding a distance to an area to a volume etc. and that would not be a physically meaningful or sensible quantity.

Comment: I didn't understand that how  [a]=s^−1 is derived. please explain that.

Comment: If a*t is dimensionless, a must compensate the dimension of t and therefore [a]=s^-1 since [t]=s.

Comment: @Pam: The dimensions of $[t]=\mathrm{s}$, i.e. time. Now, $[a]=\mathrm{s}^{-1}$ to make sure that when you multiply $at$, then units cancel each other to make a quantity that has no units, i.e. is dimensionless.

Answer (score -1):

There are one or two good general rules to remember when doing dimensional analysis.  For mathematical functions $e(argument)$, $sin(argument)$, $cos(argument)$, and $tan(argument)$, where "argument" is everything in the parentheses of the function, the argument must be dimensionless.  Thus, the "at" in the exponential must be dimensionless, which means that the dimension of $a$ must be $1/t$.

Since the argument of $e$ is dimensionless, everything in the brackets is dimensionless.  This means that $S$ must have the dimensions of $V_0/a$.  To get the dimensions of $V_0$, algebraically separate $V_0$, substitute the dimensions of the other variables, and simplify the expression.  Example:

$S=V_0/a$

Note that the brackets in the starting equation and anything else that is dimensionless, including constants, can be eliminated from the analysis without affecting the answer if I am only interested in the dimensions of a variable.  This immediately leads to:

$Sa=V_0$

S is a position, so the dimension is L.  Previous work indicates that $a$ has a dimension of $1/t$.  The dimension of $Sa$ is $L/t$, which is the dimension of $V_0$.

Comment: To whoever down-voted my answer, note that the level of the OP's question implies a beginner in dimensional analysis.  If true, a complicated answer is probably not what the OP wants.