# How makes an equation to Flipping motion

Tags: kinematics, simulations

Every now and then, I find myself reading papers/text talking about how this equation is a constraint but that equation is an equation of flipping which satisfies this constraint.
[image]

Indeed, This equation depends on other equation which is direction of hand .

If we will consider 3 axis (x,y,z) to get the behavior of page , we agree that `Z = 0` for all particles of the page at default state.

So What about the equation of each point (x,y,z) throughout flipping(browsing) ?

Besides, The position of the particle at a time $t$ is given by,

$$S(t)=\frac{V_0}{a}(1-e^{-at})$$

How to use this equation in this context ? Or is not useful for this context ?

There are :

- rectilinear motion
- uniform rectilinear motion
- sinusoidal motion
- circular motion
- ...

However, I do not know where I should classify the flipping motion to build the suitable equation which depends on: `a`(acceleration),`V`(velocity), `t`,[`X`,`Y` , `Z`] AND/OR [$$\theta$$]

Comment: Another Phys.SE post about the same function: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114852/2451

Comment: It could just be me, but I have no idea what this question is asking...

Comment: Why don't you try to contact some of the developers? And I'm not sure if the simulation is physically true.

Comment: I'm really unclear on what the question is...